# How to use knex with async/await?

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

I'm trying to use Knex with async/await since Knex has a Promise interface. My code is below.

```
const db = makeKnex({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  },
  pool: { min: 0, max: 100 },
});

async function getUsers() {
  return await db.select()
  .from('users')
  .limit(10);
}
const res = getUsers();
console.log('KNEX', res);
```

I expected to get the rows of my query back, but the output is

```
KNEX Promise {
_c: [],
_a: undefined,
_s: 0,
_d: false,
_v: undefined,
_h: 0,
_n: false }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should call await in a async signed function. Here is the pattern what I use.

```
(async function(){
  const res = await getUsers();
  console.log('KNEX', res);
})()
```

Comment: I tried this out and it worked, but I'm confused as to why it does. In my original code, `getUsers` is an async function, why didn't it work in the original?

Comment: It will work too but without `await` that code wont wait the promise result and will execute next line (console.log..). And because of that the `res` variable will be set to a `Promise` instance with `pending` state. Using the `await` keyword will ensure that, promise's `resolve` or `reject` callbacks are called.

Answer (score 7):

Async functions return promises, therefore you need to treat values returned from `getUsers` as promises, therefore `await` them or use `.then()` method on them:

```
getUsers().then((res) => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const functionName = async() => {
  let result = await db.select().('users').limit(10);
  return result;
}
```